# Xpath not found wen using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I was working on test automation, and I was googling facebook and wanted to get the links in a array list. So in my program I open up www.google.com use firefox web driver then enter facebook in search bar and then try to scan the page. I am able to open the browser and the page with facebook in search field 
but when I use `List<String>linksWOSpace=Arrays.asList(selenium.getAttribute("//li/div/h3/a"));`

it's throwing me an error that string index out of bounds -1
it's basically not able to get the elements by that xpath

Comment: The [`getAttribute()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method returns a `String`. Also, it's usage is `"locator@attribute"`. Could you please post here your expected output?

Comment: so in linksWOSpace i wanted ["Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More","Apps by Facebook - Google Play","Facebook","Facebook - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",,,,] and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that what you want is doable in one step with Selenium RC. You could do this:

```
List<String> linksWOSpace = new ArrayList<String>();

int numberOfLinks = selenium.getXpathCount("//li/div/h3/a");
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfLinks; i++) {
    // gets the <a> elements one by one
    linksWOSpace.add(selenium.getText("xpath=(//li/div/h3/a)[" + i + "]"));
}
```

The output should be a `List` of all the anchor texts.